# Apple Notarization: An error occurred while processing the json request (1268)

Tags: xcode, package, xcrun, notarization

#### Issue

I'm having an issue notarizing my app using `xcrun` command:

```
xcrun altool --notarize-app --primary-bundle-id "com.foobar.fooapp" --username="developer@foo.com" --password "@keychain:Developer-altool" --file ./myapp.pkg
```

I'm checking for notarization status using:

```
xcrun altool --notarization-history 0 -u "developer@***" -p "@keychain:Developer-altool"
```

But as I can't get anything except a `Notarization In Progress` status, it seems the notarization is failing (it generally takes around 5 min in my context).

I'm using this step by step for months and nothing seems to have changed on the Apple side since then.

#### What I tried

- I reproduced the step by step hundreds of time automatically (script), and it kept returning the same output message.
- I used the following command to review a detailed log:

```
xcrun altool --notarization-info "Your-Request-UUID" \
             --username "username@example.com" \                                    
             --password "@keychain:Developer-altool"
```

There I got a JSON URL with the message: `An error occurred while processing the json request. (1268)`

##### Question

Any idea why I can't notarize my app with the step by step above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I first checked today, the [Apple System Status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) was returning that everything was working as expected.

However, it states now that there is a `Developer ID Notary Service - Outage` on the Apple Developer side.

[image: Outage]

Therefore, the solution is probably to wait for the outage to be resolved before trying the notarization process again.

---

***EDIT:** The outage ended on Apple side and I could notarize my app again!*

[image: end outage]